# How does assigning an array of pointers to a void typecast pointer work?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting

I am trying to understand what happens in line #3.

What is the structure of `pos`. I know that removing `( void *)` from line 3 makes it an assignment of `type int*` to `int (*)[2]` and arrays are not directly copyable. So what is typecasting doing here?

```c
    int a[] = {1,5,-3};
    int * p = &a[0];
    int (*pos)[2] = ( void *)p;
    printf("%d \n",(pos[0][0])); //prints 1
    printf("%d \n",(pos[0][1])); //prints 5
    printf("%d \n",(pos[1][0])); //prints -3
    printf("%d \n",(pos[1][1])); //prints garbage
```

Comment: `pos` is a *pointer to array of two ints*, which is not compatible with `int *`. And `void*` can be converted from/to any object type, so this cast is working silently

Comment: ohh I thought its vertical size has to be defined which is not there and it confused me

Comment: That answers my query. Please put up an answer!

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)  (**note:** `int *p = a;` is fine)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin picked C up after quite some time in python. Thanks for the comprehensive rulebook though! very technical, but readable.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the rules, that catches every new C programmer. It is *array/pointer* conversion and it controls everything from how arrays are passed as parameters to why pos[1][1]` invokes *Undefined Behavior*. `pos` is a pointer to an array of int `[2]`. Valid indices are `[0][0]`, `[0[[1]` and `[1][0]` based on `a`. (you only have 3-indecies). Given the frequency it catches people -- you might as well go ahead and learn it now -- it will save you hours of headaches later `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I knew this was a very basic question, had to post from a spare account. :p One of you post an answer, that I accept and log out.

Comment: Oh, it's is -- but it isn't. If your takeaway is that "*on access an array is converted to a pointer to the first element (subject to the 4 exceptions in 6.3.2.1)*", your time and question were very worthwhile. I'd wager ~ 10-20% of array handling questions relate to it directly.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin my takeaway was about the use of void casting which allowed a pointer to be assigned to an array. p.s. writing a meta about this annoying comment help guide

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin mind posting this meta post? https://pastebin.com/pE5szmmH

Comment: @user346408 That may be the wrong takeaway. You would rather cast `int (*pos)[2] = (int(*)[2])p;` than casting through `void`. Casting though `void` will mask any type incompatibility -- Bad Juju...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  Wow that's an extension of array being pointer to first element,

Comment: What about this one [C 1D Array as 2D Subarrays by Pointers](https://pastebin.com/11i2HMe1)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oh yes, I had tested that by modifying my code too! it worked! P.S. Super neat code :)